# Change an ID with a String on SQL Query view

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL query to retrieve a few columns of a table and export them on a CSV file. However, one column use an ID (integer number). Is there any way to include something in SQL query and replace the IDs with specific strings?

For example:

```
If ID = 1 then replace it with "Dog"
If ID = 2 then replace it with "Cat"
If ID = 3 then replace it with "Apple"
```

I have only four IDs so, it will not be huge.

Here is what I have done until now to retrieve the columns I want

```
SELECT col_id, check_in, start_hour, price_total, email FROM reservations LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT case when col_id = 1 then 'Dog'
            when col_id = 2 then 'Cat'
            when col_id = 3 then 'Apple'
       end as id, 
       check_in, start_hour, price_total, email 
FROM reservations 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I used a wrong example which make you misunderstood my intentions. Please check the updated question. I apologize

Comment: That's worked. Thank you a lot and sorry for the misunderstanding of the previous example. I will choose your answer in 4 minutes. I cannot before due to the SE limit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `case/when/then` like this:

`select case when ID = 1 then 'one' else 'two' end from reservations`